# How can I execute an RSpec test suite in one app from another app's test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm writing a Ruby Gem that integrates with the testing process and I would like write integration tests  that show that it works as I expect end to end. I am including a simple application (TestApp) which uses the Gem.

My gem includes a `spec` folder, and the test app in its root. The test app includes its tests in a `features` folder. (There's other stuff in there of course).

```
my_gem
  |
  - spec
  - test_app
      |
      - features
```

Before adding the new tests, if I am in the `my_gem` directory and execute `bundle exec rspec`, my tests for `my_gem` execute as expected. If I execute:

```
cd test_app
bundle exec features
```

my tests for `test_app` execute as expected. Now if I add  to my `my_gem` tests a test:

```
describe "Test test suite"
    it "executes as expected"
        `bundle exec test_app/features`
    end
end
```

and execute the tests in `my_gem` I get the following:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:182:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could be found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
Please refer to http://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error.
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:179:in `create_default_data_source'
...
```

Following the instructions at the suggested URL leads me down a rabbit hole of adding dependencies to my gem that I would not otherwise require and don't want to force end users of the gem to depend on.

In addition to the above, I've also tried:

```
exec('bundle exec rspec test_app/features')
```

and

```
Dir.chdir('test_app') do
    `bundle exec rspec features`
end
```

but each time I get the same errors. Interestingly, I get the same errors without the extra test when I execute `bundle exec rspec test_app/features` from the `my_gem` directory in the console, but not when I execute the command without `bundle exec`. Removing `bundle exec` in the test makes no difference.

What is causing these errors and is there a way that I can execute my `test_app` test suite from within my `my_gem` tests so that they don't cause the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: http://makandracards.com/makandra/15649-how-to-discard-a-surrounding-bundler-environment

It turns out that the tests were getting executed under my current environment (someone else might be able to explain this better). The solution is to use `Bundler.with_clean_env`:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
    Dir.chdir('test_app') do
        `bundle exec rspec features`
    end
end
```